# How do prevent login sessions from persisting on Amazon.ca, aside from clicking "Sign out"?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, login, cookies

I am using Firefox 55 64-bit. The operating system is Windows 10 Pro, version 1703, build 15063.540.

My understanding of login sessions is that the website (in this case, Amazon.ca) writes a cookie to the user's terminal. My understanding is that upon closing and reopening this website, the website reads or attempts to read for this cookie. My understanding is that if the login session written in the cookie is still valid, then the website behaves as if the user has not clicked logoff (or in this case, Sign out). I believe this is similar to how StackExchange and its child sites behave when a new user does not finish signing up their account.

I am attempting to defeat this (as in my understanding of how login sessions persist) through the use of the plugin Cookie AutoDelete. The plugin is configured in Active mode, as in cookies associated with a tab are deleted upon closing said tab if no other tabs are using the cookies. This seems to be working for every site I visit *except* Amazon.ca, whose login session persists even if there is only that one tab open in Firefox. Even though I revisit Amazon.ca several times and close its tab several times, the login session persists. The predecessor of this plugin, Self-Destructing Cookies, demonstrates the same behaviour.

Since I have my Firefox configured to clear all cookies upon termination of the application, the login session does not persist between browser sessions.

How do prevent login sessions from persisting on Amazon.ca, aside from clicking "Sign out"?

Comment: "I have my Firefox configured to clear all cookies upon termination of the application". Did you also check Active Logins in the Clear All History dialog? I clear it from the dialog box rather than trusting that FF will do so upon exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I previously used [Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/) to help me with this. For any websites that you don't whitelist, the cookies (and LocalStorage, optionally) for that domain will automatically be deleted when all of its tabs are closed, after the period of time you specify, or after the browser is closed. This allows you to stay logged in on trusted sites while throwing away everything else, which can also subvert tracking cookies to some extent.

It claims not to compatible with the current FF56+ because Mozilla is moving to WebExtensions. If you're on FF 54 then you can still use it. It's currently working for me on 56 beta (you can force-install the XPI) but it may stop working at any time. Otherwise, there may be other alternatives coming out soon.

Edit: I've found a potential successor called [Cookie AutoDelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/?src=search) so I may try that out at some point.